# javascript for autobackup of tortoise svn

Tags: javascript, shell, svn, batch-file

This is the scenario.

I have to take a backup of the repository as soon as a commit takes place is Tortoise svn. I thought this could be done by configuring the post-commit hook script. But when I write the code for backup and save the file as .exe or .bat file whenever I commit something in repository I get an error "no script engine for file extension .bat/.exe".

Then I downloaded a setup for .js files. Had a simple javascript (.js) type file. It was triggered for each commit. Problem solved.

But now I need a javascript which can take a backup . How to do this. I am new to all of this. I have a shell script which can take backup but how can I use it?? Is there any way of calling the shell script from javascript?? Or is there any simple mechanism for all this auto backup stuff?? Or can I use this shell script directly as a hook script??

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use node.js for your javascript interpreter, there's [`child_process.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).